# recurrence relation: sum of first n even numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence

So base case would be
if n = 1    then  2

I'm trying to figuring out what would be the recursive case.

```
n= 1    f(1) = 2  
n= 2    f(2) = 2 + 4  =  6  
n= 3    f(3) = 2 + 4 + 6 = 12  
n= 4    f(4) = 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 = 20  
n= 5    f(5) = 2 + 4 + 6+ 8 + 10 = 30
```

I thought  n(n+1)  would be the recursive case but it's a closed-formula.

need help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some pseudo code to help you:

```
function sumeven(int n) {
    if(n == 0) return 0;
    return 2*n + sumeven(n-1);
}
```

Thus, starting at 5, the expansion becomes:

```
n=5 := 5*2 + sumeven(5-1)
n=4 := 5*2 + 4*2 + sumeven(4-1)
n=3 := 5*2 + 4*2 + 3*2 + sumeven(3-1)
n=2 := 5*2 + 4*2 + 3*2 + 2*2 + sumeven(1)
    == 10 + 8 + 6 + 4 + 2 + sumeven(0)
    == 30
```

Comment: Thank you, but what would be the value for f(0)  ??

Comment: @Jan They asked for a recursive solution. Of course a StackOverflow is possible.

Comment: Should I use two base cases then ??

Comment: @hibc It depends what inputs you're expecting. You should trap for the zero-case if you expect it to occur. Otherwise, there's no need.

Comment: You don't need a special case for n = 1

Comment: @PaulR A recursive function needs an exit condition.

Comment: Yes, but it only needs to exit at n = 0

Comment: @Jan Hmm. Interesting, I'll have to look into that. I don't think it's necessary in this case, though.

Comment: So the base case would be  if n = 0  then f(0) = 0 ?? but the first even natural number is 2..  I'm confused..

Comment: @hibc The function will count backwards from N, adding 2N each step. Once it gets to zero, it breaks out of recursion, and simply returns 0. So, while the first even number is 2, 2 is actually added last.